# Why are \showboxbreadth and \showboxdepth set to 2^{30}-1 in \loggingall?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, latex-base

The plain TeX format defines

```
\def\loggingall{\tracingcommands\tw@\tracingstats\tw@
  \tracingpages\@ne\tracingoutput\@ne\tracinglostchars\@ne
  \tracingmacros\tw@\tracingparagraphs\@ne\tracingrestores\@ne
  \showboxbreadth\maxdimen\showboxdepth\maxdimen}
```

This sets `\showboxbreadth` and `\showboxdepth` to `\maxdimen`, which is effectively 2<sup>30</sup>−1 = 1,073,741,823.

But `\showboxbreadth` and `\showboxdepth` are “integer parameters”, so aren’t they supposed to be set to 2<sup>31</sup>−1 = 2,147,483,647? Consider, say, an hbox containing 2<sup>30</sup>−1 pairs of `\kern1sp\kern-1sp` (2<sup>31</sup>−2 kern items).

Answer (score 6):

Arguably, but latex follows plain tex here, `\maxdimen` is just standing for "something big" If you really have a box with more than 2^30 nodes the chance that you want to do `\showbox` output is... slim, so it makes little difference in practice, and back then saved using up tokens for another "big number".